# Занести информацию в две таблицы

Tags: php

В одну таблицу, я заношу пользователя:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","vladon12");
mysql_select_db("testgame");
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (name,password,email,date,ip) values('$name','$password','$email','$date','$ip')") or die(mysql_error());
```

А в другую - "Героя", которого он выбрал. Можно ли это сделать так?

```
 $db2 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","vladon12");
 mysql_select_db("testgame");
 $result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `startpoke` (name....) values('$name'........)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переподключаться к БД не надо, просто:

```
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","vladon12"); 
    mysql_select_db("testgame"); 
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (name,password,email,date,ip) values('$name','$password','$email','$date','$ip')") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO startpoke (name....) values('$name'........)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: оу=) спасибо =)